# call JS function based on the JSTL <c:if> condition tag

Tags: javascript, jstl

can we call any javaScript function by using JSTL's  condition???

e.g,

```
function callAddRowFunction()
{   
    <c:if test="${ empty rolesBeans}" >
    checkDuplicteAndAddRow('categoryfields','roleId','roleName');
    </c:if>
    checkDuplicteAndAddRow('categoryfields','roleId<c:out value='${loop.count}'/>','<c:out value='${loop.count}'/>');

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think this would work. But you need to use `<c:choose>` as -

```
function callAddRowFunction()
{   
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${ empty rolesBeans}">
            checkDuplicteAndAddRow('categoryfields','roleId','roleName');
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            checkDuplicteAndAddRow('categoryfields','roleId<c:out value="${loop.count}"/>','<c:out value="${loop.count}"/>');
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you can see that i am passing one parameter which is `roleId<c:out value='${loop.count}` , this is not taken by Chrome, FF,and safari... so if you know any alternative then it will be greatfull to me... thanks in advance.... :)

Comment: This might be due to double and single quote confusion. I have edited the answer. See the method call inside <c:otherwise>.

Comment: i checked your answer, its working for <c:when> perfectly, but when i went to <c:otherwise> it was giving me null pointer exception... !!! plz help me out sir..

Comment: i checked with your latest answer!!! now exception gone!! but that dynamic values are not getting .... as i told you in my 1st comment, roleId<c:out value='${loop.count} , this is not taken by Chrome, FF,and safari...  if you know any alternative for that , plz kindly let me know...

Comment: View source of the page and see what exactly has been passing in checkDuplicteAndAddRow() method.